# Share data between two JVMs when application is clustered

Tags: java, spring, jvm, cluster-computing

I am working on a spring-boot application, which can be clustered into many instances.

The sessions data are stored and handled by Spring Session + Hazelcast, but the problem is for the cases like this one. I have a class that contains a Set of objects:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/chat/{username}")
public class ChatEndpoint {

    private Session session;
    private static Set<ChatEndpoint> chatEndpoints 
      = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();
    private static HashMap<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(
      ....
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, Message message) 
      throws IOException {
      ....
    }
   ....
}
```

In this case, the data is available locally on every instance of the JVM. How can I make this data shared between all the JVMs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have Hazelcast already available in your tech stack, use the [caching facility of Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/use-cases/caching/):

> Hazelcast is the leading in-memory data grid solution. Its java
>   caching solution enables organizations to predictably scale
>   mission-critical enterprise applications by providing in-memory access
>   to frequently used data. Hazelcast stores frequently accessed data
>   in-memory and across an elastically scalable data grid. This enables
>   any network of machines to dynamically cluster and pool both memory
>   and processors to accelerate application performance.

You can put the set of data to a cache created with Hazelcast, and access the data on other nodes in the cluster.

Comment: If you copy text from another webpage, you should mark it as a quote and add the link of the source. Otherwise it might be a copyright violation.